# Limiting name and date js cookie to load only once per session

Tags: javascript

I have a name prompt and date cookie loading on my home page, for first time visits and then subsequently as visitors come back (with the addition on a last visited message). How can I limit this last visited message to load only once per session, as currently, if someone browses my website and clicks on a link to another page (contact page for example) and then clicks back on the home page, the last visited message will load again?

The cookie itself has a 180 day expiry date, but I would like the 'last visited' message to have a time limit for each session.

Answer (score 0):

When you display the last visited message set a session cookie with no expiration date. It will be deleted when the user exits the browser. Then add a check for the existence of that cookie before displaying the message. If user session is important you can cause the session cookie to be deleted if the user ever clicks an external link or closes the window.